# Duration of extern vs static variables

Tags: c++

I understand from other online resources that `static` variables are freed in the opposite order they were declared (within the same file scope). However, I don't know how `extern` variables play into that.

For simplicity's sake lets say we have a header file:

```
//example.h
extern shared_ptr<object> pointer;
```

and a code file:

```
//example.cpp
class object { //implementation doesn't matter, just for example
};

static const object();
shared_ptr<object> pointer(object);
```

Since the duration of both `static` and `extern` variables are permanent until the execution of the program finishes, is there a guarantee by the C++ standard that one is freed first? Aka, is there a guarantee that `pointer` wont cause an access violation for trying to free already freed memory?

Comment: This `static const object();` would attempt to declare a function.

Comment: Totally agree, made it too minimal...

Comment: The lifetime rules apply to the variable *definitions*. An extern declaration just makes the name visible elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between a variable and an object. An `extern` makes it effectively an alias. It doesn't define an object. It only gives an externally defined object a name that you can use. `pointer` from `example.h` will be valid as long as `main()` remains on the callstack.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already know what you're saying unless I've missed something, my question is if I cared about errors on exiting main is there a guarantee that `object` isn't freed before `pointer` is?

Comment: @samuelnj yes, because their definition are in the same TU and in the correct order.

Comment: @samuelnj Since the `extern` is an alias, you can ignore it before you try to answer your question. Does it make sense now? That's what I meant: since it's an alias, you don't care. It doesn't by itself create or destroy any objects, not change their lifetimes, nor anything of the sort. It just lets you refer to an object from a different translation unit. If you do it when `main()` is on the callstack, you're guaranteed in your case that the object will exist - but that's true whether you do it via an alias or not. The alias changes nothing.

Comment: @KubaOber ah, makes sense now. I think I missed your point the firs time through, thanks for the clarification!